# (Java and LWJGL) using glTranslatef when loading textures?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm trying to make a 2D basic game; sort of like Terraria, to improve my openGL knowledge (using Java and LWJGL) mainly.

At the moment, i'm drawing textures on quads and everything's working fine, however, I can't seem to get this window to scroll (From what I can gather, this should be done by glTranslate..

Code:

```
private void init() {
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(window_width, window_height));
        Display.setTitle(window_title);
        Display.setVSyncEnabled(true);
        Display.create();
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    translatex = 0f;

    w = new World();
    w.placeBlock(4, 5, Blocks.STONE);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, window_width, window_height, 0, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    Font awtFont = new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 12);
    font = new TrueTypeFont(awtFont, antiAlias);
}
private void gameLoop() {
    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glLoadIdentity();
        glPushMatrix();

        glTranslatef(translatex, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_SPACE)) {
            translatex += 2.0f;
        }
        w.draw();

        inputManager();

        glPopMatrix();

        Display.update();
        Display.sync(fps);
    }
}
```

Draw method

```
public void draw() {
    texture.bind();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS); {
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2f(0, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex2f(BLOCK_SIZE, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex2f(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex2f(0, BLOCK_SIZE);
    }
    glEnd();
    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

It works fine  without the textures, but I can't make it work to save my life..
Code is set up temporarily the game loop to try and just cause some basic translation when pressing the space bar

Do I need to use a different method? How do I get this to work?

By the way, using slick-util and lwjgl libraries...

**............Edit...........**

Didn't exactly fix it, but found an alternative way round it. I modified to the draw method to take in some offset variables, and used the relative translatex to offset the quads of each texture

```
public void draw(int offset_x, int offset_y) {
    texture.bind();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(x - offset_x, y - offset_y, 0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS); {
        // Drawing the quads here
    }
    glEnd();
    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

And then called through this:

```
w.draw(translatex, 0);
```

This is only a work around, but it works, so. If anyone has an actual solution, I can't help but think it'll be more efficient...

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `glLoadIdentity` in your drawing function, reseting all the previous transformation state, especially the translation you want to apply. You seem to do this to prevent the translations per object to accumulate, but you should use the matrix stack instead, e.g. use the sequence

```
PushMatrix()
TranslateLocalTile()
Draw()
PopMatrix()
```

in your draw function, so that the local translation is encapsulated and will not affect the transformation of the next object, while all the outside transformations (like your global transformation) are still effective.